# Can someone explain the output of following statement in C?

Tags: c

I am running the following code on my console but I am unable to understand this output?Why this program doesn't throw an error but instead print a value?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  unsigned int a = -1;
   printf("%u",a);
}
```

Output : 4294967295

Comment: what error did you expect and why?

Comment: The int -1 is converted to unsigned int type because of the assignment (section 6.5.16.1 of the standard). Section 6.3.1.3.2 explains how that happens between int and unsigned int (repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type).

Comment: @idclev463035818 there was no error. It printed an integer value.

Comment: What you are getting is the maximum value of unsigned int. Since there are no memory locations for unsigned int below zero, It goes to the maximum value. Like an array of positive values where you try to get index -1, it gets the last value.

Comment: @PaulHankin I think it is taking the maximum integer value.

Comment: No, it's taking the value of the maximum unsigned int value, exactly as the standard says it should (because -1 + UINT_MAX + 1 is in range of unsigned int, and is equal to UINT_MAX).

Comment: @DevinK: Memory locations are not relevant to this. The issue is solely about values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Ah right, I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am unable to understand this output?

The `signed int` value `-1` is *converted* to `unsigned int`. From [C11 6.3.1.3p2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3) when converting a signed value to the "new type" which is `unsigned int` (you may find the [cppreference implicit conversions page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_conversions) more approachable):

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.

So `-1` is not representable in `unsigned int`. So we should add or subtract `UINT_MAX+1` to that value to get something that is representable in `unsigned int`. So we add `UINT_MAX+1` to `-1`, assuming on your platform `UINT_MAX` is `4294967295`, we get `UINT_MAX + 1 - 1 = 4294967295`. Great, now the value is representable in `unsigned int` and that value is assigned.

> Why this program doesn't throw an error

Because C is a weakly typed language in case of integer types and implicit conversions between some types are just part of the language.